# Limit the number of Keywords in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops, limit, keyword

I need help limiting the number of keywords on my page. I can call the keywords from the database ex. *$keywords* is available for them. I want to get them for every blog post.

My database table is formatted like this

```
| id     | title  | ... | keywords  |
|---------------------------------- |
| 1      | title1 | ... | word-t1-1 |
|        |        |     | word-t1-2 | 
|        |        |     | word-t1-3 |
|        |        |     |           |
| 2      | title2 | ... | word-t2-1 |
| 3      | title3 | ... | word-t3-1 |
| 4      | title4 | ... | word-t4-1 |
```

I have this code:

```
<?php 
   $kw1  = trim($keywords);
   $ct1 = explode("\n", $kw1);
   $searchkeys = "";
   for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($ct1); $i++) {
      $searchkeys = $searchkeys.'<a href="/search_results.php?keyword='.$ct1[$i].'&submit_search=">'.$ct1[$i].'</a>, ';
   }
   //echo $searchkeys;
?>
```

The code inside `for` loop shows the keywords as hyperlink

I want to know how to limit the number of printed keywords while if I define it in the `for` loop ex.

```
for ( $i = 0; i < 25; $i++){ somecode; }
```

Sometimes there aren't 25 keywords,if run the code it prints

> keyword1, keyword2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be use the `min()` function like so:

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < min(count($arr), 25); $i++ ) { // code here }
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot.